# Why does this SwiftUI LazyHStack update continuously?

Tags: swiftui

I have a large set of `URL`s to images. I display the files' thumbnails in a `LazyVStack`. I have wrapped up the 'ThumbnailView' and the 'ThumbnailGenerator' in a struct and class respectively. However, when I ran the code I discovered that it kept re-initaiting the `ThumbnailGenerator`s. After some investigation I found that after removing an `HStack` in the main view's hierarchy the problem went away.

Any thoughts as to why this might happen. (BTW I did log this with Apple, but still feel I am doing something wrong here myself.)

I have stripped the code back to the bare essentials here, replacing the thumbnail generation code with a simple sleep statement, to demonstrate the bug in action. Run it with the `HStack` in and it will print out the date continuously. Take it out and it works as expected.

```
@main
struct ExperimentApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LazyVIssue()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 140)
                .padding(100)
        }
    }
}

struct LazyVIssue: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    HStack { /// <---- REMOVE THIS HSTACK AND IT WORKS
                        ThumbnailView()
                        Text("Filename \(i)")
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThumbnailView: View {
    @StateObject private var thumbnailGenerator : ThumbnailGenerator
    
    init() {
        _thumbnailGenerator = StateObject(wrappedValue: ThumbnailGenerator())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        thumbnailGenerator.image
    }
}

final class ThumbnailGenerator: ObservableObject {
    var image : Image
    
    init() {
        print("Initiating", Date())
        image = Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle.fill")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            sleep(1)    /// Simulate some work to fetch  image
            self.image = Image(systemName: "camera.circle.fill")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening but I've seen had some funky things happen like this as well. If you initialize the ThumbnailGenerator() outside of the ThumbnailView init, I believe the issue goes away.

```
init(generator: ThumbnailGenerator) {
        _thumbnailGenerator = StateObject(wrappedValue: generator)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not clear for now what's going on here definitely (it is something about `LazyVStack` caching), but there is workaround - move everything into single row view.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct LazyVIssue: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    ThumbnailView(i)     // << single row view !!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThumbnailView: View {
    @StateObject private var thumbnailGenerator : ThumbnailGenerator
    let row: Int

    init(_ row: Int) {
        self.row = row
        _thumbnailGenerator = StateObject(wrappedValue: ThumbnailGenerator())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            thumbnailGenerator.image
            Text("Filename \(row)")
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this works in the example code here. Yet in my actual app (MacOS 11.0.1 Code 12.2) it still keeps getting called. Let me have a further experiment and see if I can get it to settle down. Thanks!